# What is keras loss class vs function?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

In Keras loss page which is [here](https://keras.io/api/losses/) there are 2 main distinction I saw is loss classes vs loss functions? Can anyone explain why for same losses these 2 APIs given? Is it just for class initialization or any other purposes? Also if anyone can explain that in which cases we should use which one that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A deep learning model can be built and trained in multiple ways.
The simplest approach to build a model would be to use Keras functional API or sequential API to build the model, use compile method to specify optimizer, loss, metrics, etc, and use the fit method for training the model.
If you choose to build the model this way the **compile** method accepts **loss class**.
**Note: You can use the loss function as well**
The actual logic that computes the loss is present in the special **call** method of a class which is used internally in the fit method.

However, there are cases (mostly in research) where the training loop has to be written in a certain way from scratch, in that case, you can use loss function to compute losses.
**Note: You can use the loss class as well**

The loss class gives you some extra functionality like specifying logit value, reduction technique, etc. So if your code requires the use of those functionality use the loss class to compute the losses.
If you do not require any such functionality you can simply use the loss function.
**Note: Under the hood, both functions call the same TensorFlow graph.**

Comment: So, if I want to use first approach which you mentioned as simplest one I can't use function way?

Comment: No, the compile method accepts anything ie function, a class object provided that it takes two arguments y_true and y_pred. So if you provide a function then it should have two arguments and if you provide a class object, its call method should have two arguments. The function or class does not necessarily have to be in built. You can create your own custom loss function/classes as well.